# issue when trying migration via Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, migration, cloud, microsoft

I want to migrate my Esxi VM from on promise to Azure cloud. I've found solution which provides it to me. Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter, provides migrating to Azure Cloud.

During migration procedure application wants " Subsciption ID and Certificate Thumbprint".

I have found generating certificate link from Microsoft. : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977336/configure-an-azure-management-certificate-so-that-microsoft-virtual-ma

After generating certificate, i've added it to Azure cloud > Management Certificates. I've also added this certificate to my Personal and Trusted Root Certificates.

But when i'm tryin to connect it gives me error.

How you ever seen this error ? Or maybe do you know any solution for handle this issue ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErjVW.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

You can try out [StarWind V2V converter](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter) to convert your VMware VM to Hyper-V (Windows) VM. StarWind V2V does support Windows Repair (in case if the VM is Windows-based) and does have possibility to switch hypervisors (vmdk -> vhdx).

**There is two possible ways to migrate the VM to the Azure:**

1) [Create and mount Azure Blob Storage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2014/01/09/mount-azure-blob-storage-as-local-drive/) as the local disk

2) Sysprep your VM (in case if it is a Windows-based VM)

3) Turn off the VM and make a convertation from VMDK to VHDX using StarWind V2V to the mounted device from azure as the file destination.

4) Create new VM in Azure and [mount](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-virtual-machines-attach-mount) prepared and converted VHDX to it.

**The second possible way:**

1) Sysprep VM

2) Turn off and convert VMware VM to VHDX to some local repository.

3) Upload VHDX to the Azure using [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed) or [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

4) Create VM and mount uploaded VHDX.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter is dead in the water since mid-2016. It's not supported, not maintained anymore and while you can find binaries still it can't do anything with VMware ESXi versions post 5.5 making it basically a no-go for modern environments.

Stick with something from the maintained list, good up-to-date snapshot of what should be used instead of MSVC.

http://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work anymore as the tool was [retired](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scvmm/2016/06/04/important-update-regarding-microsoft-virtual-machine-converter-mvmc/).

You can still use it to migrate to Hyper-V though and then manually upload the disk to Azure.

[Create a Windows VM from a specialized disk using PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized)

If you have more than one VM to migrate, I'd suggest looking at Azure Site Recovery instead.

[VMware to Azure replication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-common-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies.

I have done this via Azure Site Recovery Services.

This link helps a lot.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/physical-azure-set-up-source